# VBA loop through files remove password

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I am trying to remove passwords from multiple .xlsm files in one folder. I have written the following code, but doesn't seem to be working. I do not recieve any error however. Any help would be appreciated to figure out what I'm missing.

```
Sub RemovePasswords()

    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    
    Dim strFilename As String
    
    Dim strPassword As String
    
    Dim strEditPassword As String
    
    Dim fpath As String
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
        fpath = "C:\Users\User525\Desktop\Test Group\"        'The folder to process, must end with "\"
    
        strFilename = Dir$(fpath & "*.xls" & vbNormal) 'will open xls & xlsx etc
        strPassword = "Password"
        strEditPassword = ""
        
     While Len(strFilename) <> 0
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fpath & strFilename, _
                                        Password:=strPassword, _
                                        WriteResPassword:=strEditPassword)
            xlBook.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & strFilename, _
                          Password:="", _
                          WriteResPassword:="", _
                          CreateBackup:=True
            xlBook.Close 0
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            strFilename = Dir$()
        Wend
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you try to save the files in a different directory?

Comment: Is `"*.xls"` a typo? It should be `"*.xlsm"` according to your first sentence.